# Call C++ main classes from other file

Tags: c++

Alright so Im making a text adventure game in C++ and I am quite new to it. I'm experienced in java and some other languages. But I have a problem. I'm trying to call a class from the main file into my other file and I get an error. I get it even when I include the main.cpp in my header file or in my .cpp file. I already know that its bad practice to call .cpp's into another file, but as main has no header file I cant exactly include it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First rule; post your code.  The code itself is a much better debugging tool than your description is.  Anyhow...

> I get it even when I include the main.cpp in my header file or in my .cpp file.

This is backwards.  You include header files which contain class definitions *in the file which uses them*, not the other way around.  So...

```
// foo.h
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include <string>

class foo {
public:
    foo(const std::string& s);
    void print_whatever() const;
private:
    std::string _whatever;
};

#endif
```

---

```
//foo.cpp
#include <foo.h>
#include <iostream>

foo::foo(const std::string& s) 
  : _whatever(s) { }

void foo::print_whatever() const { 
    std::cout << _whatever; 
}
```

---

```
//main.cpp
#include <foo.h>

int main() {
    foo f("hola");
    f.print_whatever();
}
```

Comment: Alright, cool. But there can be multiple classes in the header file right? Like I can have class Player and class badGuy in the same header file?

Answer (score 3):

C++ isn't Java. Move the class declaration from your `main.cpp` into a header file and put the definition in another .cpp file.

Then include the header file in whatever file uses the class (including `main.cpp`).

Comment: Oh! I understand now! Thanks, it makes sense. Yeah its a bit confusing since in Java the classes are the files themselves.